# Row number for increasing timestmap in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have table like this :

```
col1    col2
1      2020-01-15
1      2020-01-16
1      2020-01-17
1      2020-01-18
1      2020-01-20
2      2020-01-09
2      2020-01-10
2      2020-01-15
```

and i am calcuating rank like this

```
select
    col1,
    col2,
    date_sub(col2, -row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2)) as rnk
  from myTable
```

and getting rank

```
col1    col2        rnk
1      2020-01-15   1
1      2020-01-16   2
1      2020-01-17   3
1      2020-01-18   4
1      2020-01-20   5
2      2020-01-09   1
2      2020-01-10   2
2      2020-01-15   3
```

but i need rank like this

```
col1    col2        rnk
1      2020-01-15   1
1      2020-01-16   2
1      2020-01-17   3
1      2020-01-18   4
1      2020-01-20   1
2      2020-01-09   1
2      2020-01-10   2
2      2020-01-15   1
```

changing whenever consecutive date change like 18 and 20 are not consecutive for user 1 so it is supoose to change
I am not sure how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by col1, date_add(col2, - seqnum) order by col2) as rank
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

The outer `row_number()` subtracts a sequence from `col2`.  The result is a constant when there are no gaps in adjacent values.  So, the difference defines the "islands" of adjacent records.

Comment: This eis exactly what i am looking for, you mentioned that youar subtracting but you use date_add instead of date_sub.
With date_sub it works perfect

Comment: @KumarHarsh . . . Or a negative sign.  They are equivalent.